# Can't connect to rpcbind on localhost

Tags: macos, launchd

Since upgrading to OS X 10.9 Mavericks, I can't connect to the `rpcbind` daemon anymore. `launchctl` tells me that `rpcbind` is loaded but not running:

```
$ sudo launchctl list | grep rpcbind
-   0   com.apple.rpcbind
```

But if I try to connect to it, e.g. using `rpcinfo`, the connection is refused:

```
ims ~$ rpcinfo -p
Can't contact rpcbind on localhost
rpcinfo: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused
```

How do I get `rpcbind` to start automatically when I try to connect to it?

---

Another user facing the same issue reported the following in the error log:

```
rpcbind[970]: Could not join RPC bind multicast address: Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am on Mavericks and the following starts rpcbind for me:

```
sudo launchctl start com.apple.rpcbind
```

Subsequently, the following will show that it did start:

```
 sudo launchctl list | grep rpcbind
```

Comment: However, I have the problem on 10.9 that the service seems to stop as soon as I execute rpcinfo -p

Comment: Sorry for the 2 year delay. For me, a `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.rpcbind.plist` was necessary before the `launchctl start`. Thanks!

Comment: @Feuermurmel `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.rpcbind.plist: service already loaded` but I still get `-   0   com.apple.rpcbind` ...