# How do you mount -bind a local directory?

Tags: mount, nfs

In linux, one of the great things you could do (for developers, in particular) was to mount a folder and locally bind it to another folder on the system.

This had the advantage over symlinks due do the fact tools like Git didn't detect it as being a different type of node, and you didn't need to remove the original contents. When you were done, you could simple unmount and you were left with the original filesystem contents.

However, `mount -bind` or `mount.local` don't seem to exist on Mac (as of OS X 10.10.2, Yosemite).

How do you go about this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As [mentioned by another user on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12832548/510036), you can use an NFS mount do to this. However, it requires a little bit of one-time setup.

First, you'll need to set up an `/etc/exports` file (if you haven't done so already).

```
$ sudo tee -a /etc/exports <<< "/ -alldirs -mapall=$USER localhost"
```

Secondly, you'll need to [start](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118406/cant-connect-to-rpcbind-on-localhost) the [rpc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/rpcbind.8.html) and [nfsd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/nfsd.8.html) services.

```
$ sudo launchctl start com.apple.rpcbind
$ sudo nfsd start
```

---

From there, give NFSd a little bit to wake up and get breakfast, and you should be good to mount:

```
$ sudo mount localhost:/path/to/target ./mnt
```

To restore the original contents, just do

```
$ sudo umount ./mnt
```

Comment: I tried to mount my exfat usb drive `$ sudo mount localhost:/Volumes/Aren/Movies /Users/me/Movies/`

Comment: `mount_nfs: can't mount /Volumes/Aren/Movies from localhost onto /Users/me/Movies: No such file or directory`

Comment: Its working good If I do it the other way!

Comment: If you get "No such file or directory", try making a folder to mount to on the destination first. If you get a "Permission Denied" error, try "sudo nfsd restart" (for me, nfsd was already started, so it needed restarting to pickup the new exports line, I think)

Comment: The OP stated in his comments that he wanted a solution that git would see like a normal file structure and "not detect it as being a different type of node". I just tried this solution and can confirm that *in my case*, it DOES NOT work for the purposes of git. Git doesn't see the mounted file system. If any one knows a proven method of how to do something similar that git will respect, please let it be known here. Thank you!

Comment: @JayGee I am OP. It worked for me at the time, what error does Git have? Have you `cd`ed out and then back in before using Git? Shells tend to work with file descriptors which are tied to inodes, not full string paths - so if you mount and stay in the "same" directory, the shell will still operate using the underlying directory instead of the mounted one. There's no reason Git should see anything as mounted - mounting doesn't work like that. For all intents and purposes it's the **same** type of filesystem.

Comment: Hi @Qix. Thanks for reaching out. As it turns out, it does work! But I was making the mistake of naming the folder incorrectly that I was using as the mount point. Once I fixed that, everything worked fine, even in git. This is a really cool solution to a problem I have had recently. Definitely going to use this more often.

Comment: @JayGee Glad you got it working ^^

Comment: `mount_nfs: can't mount with remote locks when server (localhost) is not running rpc.statd: RPC prog. not avail` even after `sudo launchctl start com.apple.rpcbind`.

Comment: Nice solution, although `-mapall=$USER` would also map *root* writes to `$USER`, which is often not useful. `-maproot=root` would be a better option.

Comment: To share a mounted disk, add the mountpoint to exports: `sudo tee -a /etc/exports <<< "/path/to/disk_mountpoint -alldirs -mapall=$USER localhost"` and access via `sudo mount localhost:/path/to/disk_mountpoint /path/to/new_alias`

Answer (score 9):

There is another option - [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/). It requires you to install [macFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.io/) first but provides an alternative to using NFS.

You can compile bindfs from source but it's available in [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=category&substr=fuse), [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bindfs) and [pkgsrc](http://cdn.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/filesystems/fuse-bindfs/index.html)  too.

Comment: **Homebrew:** Install [osxfuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/), then `brew install homebrew/fuse/bindfs` (Tested on El Capitan; no need for `sudo` before `bindfs` for user-oriented mounts)

Comment: Disadvantage of fuse is that it do not support inotify events. If source updated, while App watching for updates in destination, it will not receive updates.

Comment: Also it's a bit wonky for me when compiling things inside a bindfs volume. In particular I consistently get "too many open files" for one particular project in Xcode for no apparent reason. If I just copy the contents without mounting, it builds fine.

Comment: Nowadays it's called macfuse again. But it's a ton of effort to get running, requires you to disable SIP and is generally a lot of pain (thanks, Mr. Apple).