# Mount a local directory in another location of the filesystem as READ ONLY?

Tags: mount, folders, macos, filesystem

I regularly, but manually, rsync a certain local directory (A) to a remote machine. More than once I have rsynced in the wrong direction and deleted stuff that was new in A. I have backups but it takes some time to restore.

To avoid stupid mistakes like this I thought that I could mount A somewhere else in my local file system (B) and as READ ONLY so in case I perform the sync in the wrong direction nothing happens. Can this be done?

Comment: Why not do a “dry run” first with the `-n` or `—dry-run`  flags to ensure your issuing the correct command?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to put this in a script - to avoid confusing SOURCE & DESTINATION?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197029/how-do-you-mount-bind-a-local-directory seems to have an answer for this.

Comment: @Seamus I have a script but you still have to give the right command.

Comment: We’ve all been there.  Since this is a remote system, create a user with only read privileges and a username that’s clear what you “indend to do” like “syncfromremote” that can’t write to the volumes you want to protect.  I haven’t tried this but it “could” work.

Comment: @d-b: You said that you ***"regularly, but manually"*** `rsync`... if you have a script, how can you get SOURCE & DEST reversed occasionally?

Comment: @Seamus I trigger the script manually. The script takes arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question, but rather than flog that with more comments, perhaps you should consider using the `--backup-dir=DIR` option in your `rsync` command.

See `man rsync` for details, but essentially what the option does is to save all files & directories that would otherwise be deleted in the DESTINATION location to the folder designated in the `--backup-dir=DIR` option statement.

How would that help? **Assuming** your script uses an argument to set SOURCE and DESTINATION, add some `if-else` code that invokes the `--backup-dir=DIR` option statement whenever your DESTINATION is the local directory A.